# How to use two models in Django instead of using sessions, then store data to one and update these data to the second model after a successful action

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to know how I can update a Django model with the data of another Django model, after an if status == 'successful': statement in a view function, this was working well with sessions, but when you try to save to the model after a callback the session gets lost. below are my models:

```
class Hold_nominate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nomchildlast_nameho = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nomchildfirst_nameho = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nomchildageho = models.IntegerField()
    nomchilddobho = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomchildlast_nameho
    

class Nominate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_holdnom = models.ForeignKey(Hold_nominate,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nomchildlast_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nomchildfirst_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nomchildage = models.IntegerField()
    nomchilddob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomchildlast_name
```

> Bellow is my view code to save to the first Model:

```
hold_nominate = Hold_nominate.objects.create(
        nomchildlast_nameho = nomchildlast_name,
        nomchildfirst_nameho = nomchildfirst_name,
        nomchildageho = b,
        nomchilddobho =nomchildage,
        nomchildamountho =nomchildamount,
        nomspemailho =nomspemail,
        user_id=user,
        nomchildgenderho = nomchildgender,
        nomchildclasscompho = nomchildclasscomp,
        nomchildshirtho = nomchildshirt,
        nomchildhealthissueho = nomchildhealthissue,
        nomchildhealthdetailho = nomchildhealthdetail,
        nomemerphoneho = nomemerphone,
        nomspnameho = nomspname,
        nomsprelchildho = nomsprelchild,
        nomspphoneho = nomspphone,
    )
    hold_nominate.save()
```

> Below is where I am having issue to save to the second model after
> status == "successful":

```
honomx = Hold_nominate.objects.get(id=child_id)
   nomchildlast_name = honomx.nomchildlast_nameho
   nomchildfirst_name = honomx.nomchildfirst_nameho
   nomchildage = honomx.nomchildageho
   nomchilddob = honomx.nomchilddobho
   nomchildamount = honomx.nomchildamountho
   nomspemail = honomx.nomspemailho
   user_id = honomx.user_id
   nomchildgender = honomx.nomchildgenderho
   nomchildclasscomp = honomx.nomchildclasscompho
   nomchildshirt = honomx.nomchildshirtho
   nomchildhealthissue = honomx.nomchildhealthissueho
   nomchildhealthdetail = honomx.nomchildhealthdetailho
   nomemerphone = honomx.nomemerphoneho
   nomspname = honomx.nomspnameho
   nomsprelchild = honomx.nomsprelchildho
   nomspphone = honomx.nomspphoneho
if status=='successful':
nominate = Nominate.objects.create(
           nomchildlast_name = nomchildlast_name,
       nomchildfirst_name = nomchildfirst_name,
       nomchildage = nomchildage,
       nomchilddob = nomchilddob,
       nomchildamount = nomchildamount,
       nomspemail = nomspemail,
       user_id = user_id,
       nomchildgender = nomchildgender,
       nomchildclasscomp = nomchildclasscomp,
       nomchildshirt = nomchildshirt,
       nomchildhealthissue = nomchildhealthissue,
       nomchildhealthdetail = nomchildhealthdetail,
       nomemerphone = nomemerphone,
       nomspname = nomspname,
       nomsprelchild = nomsprelchild,
       nomspphone = nomspphone
       )
       nominate.save()
```